# In a topology, can one always choose a connected neighborhood of a point?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I am trying to show something that requires me finding a connected neighborhood of a point. This seems true, but I don't know why I am doubting myself:

> Let X be a topological space. If $x \in X$, then there exists an open
>   neighborhood $U$ of $x$ that is connected.

Can I just pick any open neighborhood and then if it's not connected, then decompose it into disconnected components and pick the one that $x$ is in. Then if it's still not connected then I can repeat. But I am afraid what if this procedure doesn't terminate? Is the statement above true in general?

From my book, the definition of a neighborhood is: $U$ is a neighborhood of $x \in X$ if there exists an open set $V$ such that $x \in V \subset U \subset X$.

Comment: Your suggested procedure fails not in that it doesn't terminate (it terminates after one step-- the connected component containing $x$ is connected by definition), but in that the connected components of a space need not contain a nonempty open set. Indeed, in Lord Shark's example, the connected component of $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $x$ is just $\{x\}$, which is not open.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Consider $\Bbb Q$ in its usual topology. Every subset of $\Bbb Q$ is totally
disconnected, and no point has a connected neighbourhood.

Comment: By the usual topology, do you mean the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$? In that case, given a neighborhood, how can I show that it's disconnected? What is the decomposition? Thank you for your help. I am just learning about connectedness today.

Comment: One can think of it as the subspace topology inherited from $\Bbb R$ or as a metric space itself. If $a$ and $b$ are rationals with $a<b$, then there is an irrational $\xi$ between $a$ and $b$. Then $\Bbb Q$ is the disjoint union of open sets $\{t\in\Bbb Q:t<\xi\}$ and $\{t\in\Bbb Q:t>\xi\}$. Thus no subset of $\Bbb Q$ containing $a$ and $b$ can be connected.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thank you so much. I was just confused on the openness of neighborhoods and the openness requirements of connected component (and how they are both open and closed in the relative topology).

Answer (score 2):

Your question has a negative answer. However, there are some special cases in which the answer is trivially "yes". Assume that $X$ has only finitely many connected components. These are closed and therefore also open (because their number is finite). Then the component of any point $x$ is a connected open neighborhood of $x$.

But there is a more interesting situation. In your question you write
"Can I just pick any open neighborhood and then if it's not connected, then decompose it ...". This indicates that you hope that each open neighborhood $U$ of any $x$ contains a connected open neighborhood $V$ of $x$. This is of course not true in general, but spaces having this property received an own name: These are the *locally connected spaces*. For example, open subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$ are locally connected.